# PHP ext/curl.so Hardcoding verbose option

Tags: php, c, curl, logging

Hello guys i want to hardcode verbose option directly into the php curl library...
But i am not really a C developer...

https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/curl

This is basically the source code for it

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/72bd55902d1908857f47555ad69458861e1acd94/ext/curl/interface.c#L1756

Here you can enable the verbose option..

But i am not being able to configure it to write output log file in C like below in php...

```
$verbose = fopen('./curl.log', 'w+');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
```

I would like to write directly /var/curl.log without any modification to php files.

Comment: You would not only have to set that option itself, the equivalent of `$verbose = fopen(…)` would have to happen somewhere as well. Not sure if that can even be achieved, with any reasonable effort. And even if you somehow got this to work, every time an error occurred and you did not find an entry in your log, you’d still be left guessing whether that was due to your own modifications of the library now, or something else … This sounds like an overall bad idea to me.

Comment: ...and you would need to implement the same everytime there's an update, or you would be stuck with an older version with potential bugs/security issues.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just create a class that wraps curl and always sets it for you?

Comment: well i understand the drawbacks.. but i cannot to modify the php code because that is not maintained by me... i just want to to keep a record what network calls it is making... ive also tried proxying but messes the ssl part :(

Comment: Are you really sure you understand the drawbacks? This is really a terrible idea. You CAN use a proxy as long as the proxy handles SSL interception.